# Mysql select column depending on column sum results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
DESCRIPCION,
MEDICION,
UNIDAD,
PRECIOUNITPROV1,
PRECIOUNITPROV1 * medicion AS IMPORTE1,
PRECIOUNITPROV2,
PRECIOUNITPROV2 * medicion AS IMPORTE2,
PRECIOUNITPROV3,
PRECIOUNITPROV3 * medicion AS IMPORTE3     
FROM
contcomparativos
    INNER JOIN
comparativos ON comparativos.codobra = contcomparativos.codobra
    AND comparativos.numcomp = contcomparativos.numcomp
WHERE
comparativos.user = 'root'
    AND comparativos.codobra = '39E'
    AND comparativos.familia = 'ANDAMIOS SUSPENDIDOS'
```

What I´m trying to get is only have one column of this 3 columns -> IMPORTE1, IMPORTE2 OR IMPORTE3.

And the criteria for choosing the right column is :

least (sum(IMPORTE1), sum(IMPORTE2), sum (IMPORTE3))

therefore I want to have only in my query de IMPORT? column which has the less SUM value

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have 3 columns?

Comment: Because I don't know how achieve what  I need, this query is my starting point.Thanks

Comment: Ok. Step 1. See normalization!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `LEAST()` in MySQL.

This may work

```
SELECT 
    DESCRIPCION,
    MEDICION,
    UNIDAD,
    PRECIOUNITPROV1,
    PRECIOUNITPROV1 * medicion AS IMPORTE1,
    PRECIOUNITPROV2,
    PRECIOUNITPROV2 * medicion AS IMPORTE2,
    PRECIOUNITPROV3,
    PRECIOUNITPROV3 * medicion AS IMPORTE3,
    (CASE LEAST(SUM(PRECIOUNITPROV1 * medicion),SUM(PRECIOUNITPROV2 * medicion),SUM(PRECIOUNITPROV3 * medicion)) WHEN SUM(PRECIOUNITPROV1 * medicion) THEN 'PRECIOUNITPROV1' WHEN SUM(PRECIOUNITPROV2 * medicion) THEN 'PRECIOUNITPROV2' WHEN SUM(PRECIOUNITPROV3 * medicion) THEN 'PRECIOUNITPROV3' END) AS Least_Sum_Column_Name      
    FROM
    contcomparativos
        INNER JOIN
    comparativos ON comparativos.codobra = contcomparativos.codobra
        AND comparativos.numcomp = contcomparativos.numcomp
    WHERE
    comparativos.user = 'root'
        AND comparativos.codobra = '39E'
        AND comparativos.familia = 'ANDAMIOS SUSPENDIDOS'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, but LEAST() gives me the SUM value, but what I need is to choose the column that has the minimun SUM value of these 3 columns. Thanks

Comment: it doesn't work because only gives one row, and I need the entire column. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: This is a dynamic SQL (Hope it helps)

```
SELECT (
SELECT CASE
 WHEN (Sum(PRECIOUNITPROV1 * MEDICION) < Sum(PRECIOUNITPROV2 * MEDICION))
 AND (SUM(PRECIOUNITPROV1 * medicion) < SUM(PRECIOUNITPROV3 * medicion))
 THEN 'PRECIOUNITPROV1 * medicion'
 WHEN (Sum(PRECIOUNITPROV2 * MEDICION) < Sum(PRECIOUNITPROV1 * MEDICION))
 AND (SUM(PRECIOUNITPROV2 * medicion) < SUM(PRECIOUNITPROV3 * medicion))
 THEN 'PRECIOUNITPROV2 * medicion'
 WHEN (Sum(PRECIOUNITPROV3 * MEDICION) < Sum(PRECIOUNITPROV2 * MEDICION))
 AND (SUM(PRECIOUNITPROV3 * medicion) < SUM(PRECIOUNITPROV1 * medicion))
 THEN 'PRECIOUNITPROV3 * medicion'
 END)
into @SelectedCol
FROM contcomparativos
    INNER Join
comparativos ON comparativos.codobra = contcomparativos.codobra
    AND comparativos.numcomp = contcomparativos.numcomp
WHERE
comparativos.user = 'root'
    AND comparativos.codobra = '39E'
    AND comparativos.familia = 'ANDAMIOS SUSPENDIDOS';
SET @user = 'root';
SET @codobra = '39E';
SET @familia = 'ANDAMIOS SUSPENDIDOS';

SET @sql = CONCAT('
SELECT
DESCRIPCION,
MEDICION,
UNIDAD,
PRECIOUNITPROV1,
PRECIOUNITPROV1 * medicion AS IMPORTE1,
PRECIOUNITPROV2,
PRECIOUNITPROV2 * medicion AS IMPORTE2,
PRECIOUNITPROV3,
PRECIOUNITPROV3 * medicion AS IMPORTE3,',
@SelectedCol, ' AS Least_PRECIOUNITPROV
FROM
contcomparativos
    INNER Join
comparativos ON comparativos.codobra = contcomparativos.codobra
    AND comparativos.numcomp = contcomparativos.numcomp
WHERE
comparativos.user = ', @user,
    'AND comparativos.codobra = ', @codobra,
    'AND comparativos.familia = ', @familia );

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: your solution it seems to be the correct one, but the first column below is the right result but I´m having the second one, I don't know why.....

column correct: 1312, 2670, 3600,600    
column obtained: 1312,2580,3600,240

Comment: I was reading again your question and I'm not sure that my answer is what you need because it gives values  from different columns for each row, conversely (it seems) you need values from the same column on each row

Comment: yes that´s corrent I need all the resuts form the same column. Thanks

Comment: @AntonioLopezsLopes I edited my answer using a dynamic SQL. Try it

Comment: Upps, I haven't had luck:

**Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'comparativos.codobra = 39EAND comparativos.familia = ANDAMIOS SUSPENDIDOS' at line 17**

Comment: please check all single quote

Comment: I have reviewed the coutes but still I'm getting an error:
**Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Least_PRECIOUNITPROV FROM contcomparativos     INNER JOIN comparativos ON compar' at line 10**

Comment: Sorry for not helping

Comment: No problem, Thanks anyway